# Python - How to put print statements from different parts of code into different spots?

Tags: python, variables, printing

So I'm making a game that lets people make a face of a character using ASCII art, and I have split all of the questions about the facial features into different parts of the code, and all of the questions and variables for the facial features are in different classes. I want to make all of the prints of the facial features to appear on top of each other  at the bottom of the code.

Lets say the user selects spiky hair , big eyes, a small nose, and a small mouth for my example, but the user selects the features at different places in the code, and if I were to print the features after the selection, the face would be chopped up, like this(output):

Choose a hair:
"spiky"
This is your hair: "|///|"

Choose some eyes:
"big"
These are your eyes: " O  O "
...

BUT, I want the code to be like this(output):

Choose a hair:
"spiky"

Choose some eyes:
"big"
....

These are your features:
|///|
 O   O 
...

Any tips on how too make that happen?

Comment: Can you post the code you have thus far?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly how you're going about this, but architecting it with all your variables in separate classes doesn't sound like it makes sense for what you're trying to do.  You could use a single class to hold all the information about the character:

```
class Character():
    hair = ""
    eyes = ""

    def description(self):
        description = "These are your features: "
        if self.hair == "spiky":
            description += "|///| "
        elif self.hair == "smooth":
            description += "---- "

        if self.eyes == "big":
            description += "O O"
        elif self.eyes == "small":
            description += "o o"

        return description

def main():
    character = Character()
    character.hair = input("What kind of hair would you like? ")
    character.eyes = input("What kind of eyes would you like? ")
    print(character.description())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Hopefully that helps!